# "No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.get()" after upgrading react-native-code-push from 7.0 to 8.0

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

After upgrading react-native-code-push from 7.0.x to 8.0.1 with React Native 0.70.x, `npx react-native run-android` started to throw error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle' line: 6. //<<== 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), grep(), grep()
```

The line 6 in code push.gradle is:

```
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName.get() ?: "index.android.bundle"
```

Comment: I got the same error @user938363, did you manage to fix it since? :/